# Strong name signing of .NET assemblies

Tags: c#, .net, reverse-engineering

Why couldn't I create a new assembly and sign it using the same public key as the previous one in order to maliciously substitue it ? It have to work cause the only information about external assemblies being used in current assembly is their public key token, physical name and version. There is no digital signature.

```
.assembly extern mscorlib
{
  .publickeytoken = (B7 7A 5C 56 19 34 E0 89 )                         // .z\V.4..
  .ver 4:0:0:0
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If the reference contained the actual signature then the assembly you're referencing could never be updated in any way.

Instead, your assembly says "I want an assembly with name X, version Y, and signed by well know public key Z". The system then locates an assembly with name X, version Y, and claiming to be signed by public key Z and checks that it *has* been signed by private key Z<sup>k</sup> (the private key that corresponds with public key Z). *Verifying* the signature requires only the public key Z.

Comment: Private and public keys are mathematically connected and I may use any private key which does not contradict my public key to sign the assembly. And then I may generate a signature and this signature will be valid.

Comment: @Ilia - if you believe you have a technique to take a given public key (token) and generate a private key that works with it, please share that with the world - it would be news.

Comment: @Ilia - e.g. take [RSA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_(cryptosystem)). The public key is an exponent, `e` *and* the modulus `n`. It's trivial to create another private/public key pair that uses the exponent `e`. It's *not* trivial to create another private/public key pair that share exponent `e` and modulus `n`.

Comment: @Ilia The fact that they are "mathematically connected" doesn't mean that it's trivial to find out the private key just by knowing the public key. Asymmetric ciphers like this make it very easy to get a public key from the private key, and to validate a signature made with the private key while only having the public key, but getting the private key from the public key requires a lot of work. Quantum computers might change that some day, but we already have asymmetric ciphers that are secure even against that - we'll "just" have to switch.

Comment: Damien, you should make it clear that the one who verifies the assembly *doesn't need the private key*. Anyone who knows anything about asymmetric ciphers will know, but others might be confused.

Comment: My way of thinking was more like this: public key is {m*n} and private key is {m,n}, hence I could take ANY pair of multipliers and sign the assembly and this new private key would be different but still valid.

Comment: @Ilia - if you're referring to, say, the `p` and `q` values that are used in RSA, the key aspect here is that they're primes. Due to prime factorization we know that there is only one pair of integers that produce the result `p*q`. So there aren't another pair you can select - you have to find exactly `p` and `q`, and it's the difficulty of deriving those given just `p*q` that is at the core of RSA.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever ty, its pretty clear right now

Answer (score 2):

The public key token isn't the only information stored in the signed assembly. Let's see how strong naming works in short:

- You create a public-private key pair as usual
- The assembly is compiled as usual
- A hash of the assembly is computed, and signed with the private key. This value is stored in the signed assembly.
- The public key of the pair is also stored in the assembly

The asymmetric part is the key point - when the runtime computes the hash of the assembly when loading, it can compare the signatures using *just* the public key - but to actually *create* the signature, you need the *private* key.

The security mostly hinges on the complexity of finding the private key from the information you do have at hand, and from the unlikelyhood of guessing the proper signature from just the hash and the public key. On classical computers and with reasonably big keys, this is going to take a long time.

So, you trust the public key, because you know the developer associated with it. And you know that the given assembly was indeed produced by this developer, because you can verify the actual binary data of the assembly against the key to make sure it could only be signed by someone who has the private key associated with the given public key. This also makes it safe against modification - if you make a change in the assembly, you also need to change the hash-signature, and you need the private key to do that.